# How can I change the color of textOut of TCanvas (delphi)?

Tags: delphi, tcanvas

I am drawing text on TCanvas using `TextOut()` but I need a different text color.

What can I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the color of the canvas's Font

```
Canvas.Font.Color := <whatever>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also You can change canvas style

```
Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
```